# If statement confuses me

Tags: javascript, if-statement, slider

I have this code here for a slider and I don't understand what if statement does.

In my head are 2 options

First, if the `current === sliderImages.length - 1` then `current === 1`, second, if the `current === sliderImages.length - 1` then the `current === 2` (the length of the array) then take away one.

Here is my (JavaScript) code:

```
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
  arrowLeft = document.querySelector("#arrow-left"),
  arrowRight = document.querySelector("#arrow-right"),
  current = 0;

// Clear all images
function reset() {
  for (let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
    sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Init slider
function startSlide() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[0].style.display = "block";
}

// Show prev
function slideLeft() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = "block";
  current--;
}

// Left arrow click
arrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (current === 0) {
    current = sliderImages.length;
  }
  slideLeft();
});

// Show next
function slideRight() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = "block";
  current++;
}

// Right arrow click
arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
    current = -1;
  }
  slideRight();
});

startSlide();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem comes from thinking about specific numbers on your array. Imagine instead you have an array with `n` numbers.

```
if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
  current = -1;
}
```

The `sliderImages.length` would be `n` (10 for example, or 20, any number).

Your `current` variable tells you which image you're currently showing. So if you click the Right Arrow then you want to move one step to the right. But if you're on the last position of the array, the *next* image, would be the *first* image. So you do `current = -1`

In other words: that if is checking whether you're in the last image if so, move back to the first position on the array.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer,i know that 'current' must be set on'-1 'because when i hit the right button it adds one.But i don't understand how i m supposed to read (current===sliderImages.length-1)

Comment: You can read it literally "if current is equal to how many items are in slider images minus one". Not sure if that helps. Maybe I'm missing your point